# await no espera con mongo.connect

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promesas

Mi intención inicial es diseñar una forma de "amaestrar" las promesas para poder pedir un resultado a una función asíncrona y asegurar que al volver de la llamada, el resultado esté resuelto.

Estoy tratando de usar esta función para obtener un objeto con el cual manipular una BD Mongo:

```
async function abreMongo() {
    console.log("abre Mongo")
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, Server = 
    require('mongodb').Server;

    var cliente = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));

    try {
        //var mongo = await cliente.open();
        console.log("1. Aguaita connect")
        var mongo = await cliente.connect()
        console.log("Tipo de respuesta: "+mongo)
        console.log("   Conectó")
        console.log("2. Inicializo bdMng")
        bdMng = mongo.db("Asistencia");
        console.log("   Inicializó bdMng")
        console.log("3. Cierra el cliente")
        cliente.close();
        console.log("Retorna Mongo")
        return mongo;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

El caso es que en cuanto ejecuto esperaría que los tres primeros mensajes fueran:
1. Aguaita connect
Tipo de respuesta: << tipo >>
   Conectó

(Puse lo de "tipo de respuesta" por si connect retornaba una promesa)

Lo que recibo como respuesta es esto:

```
Va a Abre Mongo
abre Mongo
1. Aguaita connect
Retornó de Abre Mongo

<< Mensajes de código posterior a la llamada a "abreMongo" >>

   Tipo de respuesta: [object Object]
   Conectó
2. Inicializo bdMng
   Inicializó bdMng
3. Cierra el cliente
Retorna Mongo
```

Es evidente que el await para connect no está funcionando según la teoría.

¿Sabe alguien qué estoy haciendo mal o si ese es el comportamiento esperado?

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje que mencionas: `Retornó de Abre Mongo` no es parte de tu función `async`, imagino que lo tienes fuera de la misma. Es por ello que se muestra antes que el resto.

Esto es porque toda función [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) devuelve una Promesa. Si tienes una llamada a una función `async` en tu código, el resultado de esta será resuelto (o no) en algún momento futuro. Es por ello que te muestra lo que ves.

Una de las confusiones más grandes que se generan con las funciones `async` es que se piensa que el código asíncrono que se ejecuta dentro de ellas será *convertido* mágicamente a código sincrónico por el simple uso de la palabra `await`.

Realmente lo que sucede es que dentro de la función `async` todo el código que va después de cada llamado a un proceso asíncrono con `await` se ejecutará cuando dicho proceso finalice. Pero esto ocurrirá sólo para el código que está dentro de la función `async`. El código que está después del llamado a la función `async`, seguirá ejecutándose mientras se resuelve *asíncronamente* la función `async`.

Un ejemplo sencillo sería el siguiente:

```js
const abreMongo = async () => {
  console.log('Dentro de abre mongo');
  try {
    console.log('Paso 1');
    const mongo = await Promise.resolve('Algo');
    console.log('Promesa resuelta');
    console.log('Retorna mongo');
    return mongo;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('Uuuuupss');
    console.error(e.message);
    throw e;
  }
}

console.log('Empecemos');
abreMongo();
console.log('Are we done yet?');
console.log('Are we done yet?');
console.log('Are we done yet?');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Como puedes observar se ejecutan todas la llamadas a `console.log()` antes de que se resuelva la promesa.

## ¿Cómo domamos la Promesa?

Pues como toda Promesa implementa los métodos `then()` y `catch()`, podemos usar los mismos para trabajar con los resultados.

Otra opción es envolver todo nuestro programa en una función `async` autoejecutada y así podríamos usar directamente `await` cuando fuera el caso.

**Usando `then` y `catch`**

```js
const abreMongo = async () => {
  console.log('Dentro de abre mongo');
  try {
    console.log('Paso 1');
    const mongo = await Promise.resolve('Algo');
    console.log('Promesa resuelta');
    console.log('Retorna mongo');
    return mongo;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('Uuuuupss');
    throw e;
  }
}

console.log('Empecemos');
abreMongo()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('Are we done yet?');
    console.log('Resultado: ', result);
    console.log(`We are done, please stop asking.`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y entiendas la forma correcta de *domar* las Promesas.

Comment: Este es el mejor tutorial de async/await que he leído.

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudar a aclarar dudas. Me costó un mundo entender esto cuando lo vi por primera vez también. Saludos